# Нормы для транслитерации английских слов

Tags: заимствования

И такой вопрос. Есть ли какие-то нормы для транслитерации английских слов? Мне кажется, что транслитерировать нужно так, как эти слова слышатся, а не так, как пишутся (в английском языке это разные вещи). А то говорят и "ланч", и "ленч", "Сандра Баллок" и "Сандра Буллок", "Ким Бессинджер" и "Ким Бессингер".
По-моему, произносить по буквам - это все равно, что читать вместо "Рено" - 
"Ренаулт"))) Но тем не менее, может, для этого есть какие-то правило?

Comment: И все это рядом с Гудзоновым заливом (Hudson). Я, помнится, поспорила даже как-то со своим преподавателем английского (в аспирантуре). Я прочитала по-английски "Тексас", а она поправила "Техас". Но никакому американцу не придет в голову прочитать Texas со звуком "h"!

Comment: Когда-то в русском звук Г был как в украинском (вроде звонкого Х). И в английском тогда буква **h** передавала ровно тот же звук. Оттуда, скорее всего, и пошли эти "традиционные" транслитерации известных имён и названий: Гарри, Робин Гуд, Говард, Гарвард, Гамбург и т.д. Разумеется, теперь это имеет мало смысла: в английском звук превратился в лёгкий выдох, а у нас в твёрдое "г".

Answer (score 2):

«Транслитерировать так, как слова слышатся» невозможно по той причине, что это будет не транслитерация, а транскрипция. :) На самом деле, при передаче англоязычных собственных наименований используются оба способа, притом зачастую они причудливо переплетаются в пределах одного слова (!). Это не очень-то последовательный путь, но, на мой взгляд, более разумный, чем остановиться на каком-то одном из способов. Разночтения имеют место, да. Но большой проблемы я в этом не вижу. Сандра Баллок не Шекспир (прошу прощения, Уилъям Шэйкспиа :), в отношении графической фиксации её имени ещё не сформировалось традиции.

Comment: Я понимаю, просто, например, меня коробит, когда по-русски произносят не так, как оно произносится в оригинале. С этими актрисами - это первое, что пришло в голову. И хорошо бы еще какие-то звуки, которых в русском языке нет, вроде [th] (да и то, читать его как "ф" я считаю совершенно неправильным), но путать А и У...

Comment: На интуитивном уровне я с вами кое в чём согласен. Но меня «Баллок» не коробит, честное слово. :)

Comment: Ну так Баллок и соответствует произношению, разве не так?

Comment: Не так. Она Буллок [ˈbʊlək].

Answer (score 1):

Разумнее - передавать звучание, но с учетом русских языковых обычаев. Передавать буквы - глупо, это и "рено", и "пежо" и куча других примеров подтверждают нелепость копирования иностранной грамматики. Ну, исторически попалось несколько исключений, типа "теХаса", что ни о чем не говорит и ничего не доказывает. Например, для русского языка гораздо удобнее произносить "адоб", а не корчиться с "эдоуб", привычнее звучит "альфавилла", а не "альфавиль". Ещё одно золотое правило, на мой взгляд, - не плодить лишних букв в угоду языку-оригиналу. НО самую большую проблему для школьников, студентов и просто русских людей создают чинуши от языка, которые записывают в словари иностранные слова, где просто путают оригинальные буквы и звуки или просто пишут "от балды" (просто это не поддаётся буквально НИКАКОЙ логике) и получается абракадабра, которую невозможно запомнить, так как даже знаток языка-оригинала напишет с ошибкой.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с предыдущим ответом. Если уж совсем невтерпёж, то после написания на русском можно поставить скобки и указать оригинал на английском (хинди, пушту, иврит...)

Comment: А представляете, какие проблемы при транслитерации с французского на английский и наоборот! Они, кажется, ничего и не меняют.

Comment: Меняют. И еще как...

Comment: Можно проиллюстрировать хотя бы парочкой примеров?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос очень интересный и очень сложный. Считаю, что нужно ввести норму написания имен и названий на языке оригинала. По крайней мере, для языков, использующих латиницу. Венгры в принципе так и делают - не переводят имена на свой язык (фонетика ведь своя!), а пишут как в оригинале, что иногда приводит к курьезам. Другой вопрос, что они используют латиницу, а в русском кириллица. С иероглифическими языками и арабской вязью, честно, не знаю что делать. Там уж точно придется использовать фонетический принцип. Но коробит от того, что при переводе названий получаются разночтения. Например, Мацушита - Мацусита. При этом по-английски Matsushita. Или, есть такой очень умный дядька - Лайнус Полинг. У него много работ во многих сферах науки. В первую очередь, физика и химия. Кто ж знал, что на самом деле он [Pauling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linus_Pauling), т.е. Паулинг. И переводные книжки за его авторством каждый переводчик озаглавливает как может :-( Про немецкие фамилии вообще промолчим (вроде Гёте и Рёрих, где должно быть "Ё", хотя по-русски обычно пишут как Гете и Рерих, соответственно)

В общем, головная боль та еще. Я видел пару книжек, где были описаны рекомендации перевода названий, но ссылки, увы, потерял. Если кто-нибудь сможет их восстановить - был бы очень признателен.

Ссылки:

wikipedia

Comment: Один наш профессор говорил "Ляйбниц", "Кляйн", "Ляйпциг". Но у меня что0то язык не поворачивается...